# How to solve using Cauchy Integral formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $C$ be the positively oriented boundary of the square whose sides lie along the lines $x=+/-2$ and $y=+/-2$. I am supposed to use the Cauchy Integral formula to evaluate $$\int_C \frac{cosz}{z(z^2+8)}\mathrm{d}z$$
This is the formula $$\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}z=\frac{2i\pi}{n!}f^{n}(z_0)$$

What would $z_0$ represent in this case? I know I have to manipulate the denominator somehow, but am stuck...

Comment: Use $z_0=0$. The second factor of the denominator has zeros outside of $C$, therefore you can put it in $f$.

Comment: @arbautjc Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\,z^2+8=0\iff z=\pm\, 2\sqrt 2\,i\,\Longrightarrow\,$ the function

$$f(z):=\frac{\cos z}{z^2+8}$$

is analytic on and inside the given square, and thus only zero is a simple pole of the function

$$\frac{\cos z}{z(z^2+8)}=\frac{f(z)}{z}$$

so by the theorem you mention:

$$\oint\limits_C\frac{\cos z}{z(z^2+8)}dz=\oint\limits_C\frac{f(z)}{z}dz=2\pi if(0)=\ldots$$